# Ajax no funciona

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

- Carpeta contenedora:

  - Carpeta js

    - Sub-Carpeta `ajax`

      - Archivo JS `ajaxlogin.js`
  - Carpeta `php`

    - Archivo PHP `consultas.PHP`
  - Archivo HTML `index.html`

Mi código es el siguiente:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ES-MX">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, Initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">

<title>Login HTML,JS,PHP y MySQL </title>
</head>
<body>

<header class="card-header text-center">
    <h1><strong>Ejemplo Login</strong></h1>
    <h5>HTML, JS, PHP y MySQL</h5>      
</header>
<section class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center row-login">
            <div class="col-5 form_login bg-light">
                <div class="row bg-primary text-white justify-content-center"><h3 class="text-center">Iniciar Sesión</h3></div>
                <div id="warning-div" class="row bg-warning justify-content-center display-none">
                    <small id="warning-text" class="text-center">           
                    </small>
                </div>  
                <div class="">
                    <form action="">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="login">Usuario:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="txtUsuario" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario" id="loginUsuario">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="login_con">Contraseña:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="txtContraseña" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" id="loginContrasena">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAceptar" onclick="login()">Aceptar</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
<footer class="card-footer bg-dark text-white text-center ">Copyright 2017</footer>
<script src="js/ajax/ajaxlogin.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**consultas.php**

```
<?php
include("bd/conexionbd.php");
$usuario=$_POST['Usuario'];
$contrasena=$_POST['Password'];

$cmd= $conn->prepare('SELECT usuario, rol_usuario.nombre_Rol FROM usuario inner join rol_usuario on usuario.id_Rol=rol_usuario.id_Rol where Usuario=? AND Contrasena=?');
$cmd->bind_param('ss',$nom_usuario, $usuario_cont);
$nom_usuario=$usuario;
$usuario_cont=md5($contrasena);
$cmd->execute();

/*Se vincula las variables al resultado*/
$cmd->bind_result($user,$rol);
/*Almacenar el resultado*/
$cmd->store_result();
/*Se comprueba si hay resultados*/
if ($cmd->num_rows>0) {
echo'hay resultados';
$cmd->fetch();
echo "$user"." ".$rol;
}else{
echo 'no hay resultados';
}

?>
```

**ajaxlogin.js**

```
function login(){
if ($('#loginUsuario').val()===""|| $('#loginContrasena').val()==="") {
    $('#warning-div').css({
        'display': 'block'
    }); 
    $('#warning-div').addClass('row bg-danger justify-content-center text-center');
    $('#warning-text').addClass('text-white');
    document.getElementById('warning-text').innerHTML='Hay Campos Vacios';  
}else{

    var usuario= $('#loginUsuario').val();
    var password =$('#loginContrasena').val();

        ajaxLogin(usuario,password);

    }
}

function ajaxLogin(usuario,password){
alert('Entraste al ajax');

$.ajax({
    url: '../../php/consultas.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: "Usuario="+usuario+"&Password="+password,
    beforeSend: function(){
        $('#warning-div').css({
        'display': 'block'
    }); 
    $('#warning-div').addClass('row bg-warning justify-content-center text-center');
    $('#warning-text').addClass('text-white');
    document.getElementById('warning-text').innerHTML='Iniciando Sesión...';    
    },
})
.done(function() {
    console.log("success");
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log('Error');   })
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
});


}
```

**La idea es:** Obtener las ***dos columnas*** de la `consulta MySQL` mediante la funcion `ajax()` y redireccionar según el valor de la columna rol (usuario o administrador). El problema es que el ajax no funciona.

Comment: has revisado la consola o el network ? te saca algún error ?

Comment: Que error te marca o cual es el problema?

Comment: Lo mismo que te comenta camilo, checa la consola de tu navegador web para ver que te arroja la petición AJAX con Control + Shift + i , y veo que cargas primero tu archivo `<script src="js/ajax/ajaxlogin.js"></script>` y luego el archivo `<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>` cuando esto es al reves, primero cargas tu archivo jquery y luego ya todo lo demas

Comment: No recibe el `Sucess`. Le puse un `alert()` en la función fail y es lo que solo me está devolviendo, pero no me devuelve nada en el `.done()`

Comment: A ver o `done` o `fail`... si entra en el `fail` no te puede entrar en el `done`. Significa que hay un problema, y casi siempre es el archivo PHP (el código)  `../../php/consultas.php` o la ruta del archivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He probado tu código y está *casi* bien, salvo unas pequeñas cosas:

El `done` necesita recibir el parámetro de lo que obtiene del servidor:

```
.done(function(data) {  ...
```

y puedes hacer una prueba de lo que está devolviendo:

```
console.log(data);
```

La función `ajaxLogin` quedaría así:

```
function ajaxLogin(usuario,password){
alert('Entraste al ajax');

$.ajax({
    url: 'ok.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: "Usuario="+usuario+"&Password="+password,
    beforeSend: function(){
        $('#warning-div').css({
        'display': 'block'
    }); 
    $('#warning-div').addClass('row bg-warning justify-content-center text-center');
    $('#warning-text').addClass('text-white');
    document.getElementById('warning-text').innerHTML='Iniciando Sesión...';    
    },
})
.done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log('Error');   })
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
});


}
```

---

**Notas:**

Para que esto funcione me aseguré de que:

- El archivo PHP que llama ajax funciona adecuadamente
- La ruta de dicho archivo es correcta
- La librería jQuery está debidamente cargada

Yo pondría todas mis funciones jQuery dentro de `function`, para que no intenten correr antes de que el DOM esté listo.

Comment: bien jugado mi estimado, eres grande bro :D

Comment: @A.Cedano Excelente, ha sido de gran utilidad, muchas gracias por el aporte.

Comment: Aparte de todo eso, creo que también tuvo que ver la ruta del archivo `consultas.php` de manera relativa no me encontraba el archivo.