# Ayuda peticion al servidor desde ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax, push-notification, push

Necesito hacer una consulta al servidor si hay un nuevo valor en una tabla o no yy si lo hay que me mande una notificacion de que hay un nuevo valor estuve mirando y la mejor opcion seria con ajax pero no tengo muy bien claro como hacerlo

este es el .php que registra en la DB

```html
?php
include('is_logged.php');//Archivo verifica que el usario que intenta acceder a la URL esta logueado
/* Connect To Database*/
require_once ("../config/db.php");//Contiene las variables de configuracion para conectar a la base de datos
require_once ("../config/conexion.php");//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos
$action = (isset($_REQUEST['action'])&& $_REQUEST['action'] !=NULL)?$_REQUEST['action']:'';
if (isset($_GET['Nticket'])){
    $incidencia=intval($_GET['Nticket']);
    $query=mysqli_query($con, "select * from ticket where Nticket='".$Nticket."','".$incidencia."'");
    $rw_user=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $count=$rw_ticket['Nticket'];
    if ($Nticket!=1){
        if ($delete1=mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM ticket WHERE Nticket='".$Nticket."'")){
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <strong>Aviso!</strong> Datos eliminados exitosamente.
        </div>
        <?php 
    }else {
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <strong>Error!</strong> Lo siento algo ha salido mal intenta nuevamente.
        </div>
        <?php

    }

    } else {
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <strong>Error!</strong> No se pudo eliminar ésta  categoría. Existen productos vinculados a ésta categoría. 
        </div>
        <?php
    }



}
if($action == 'ajax'){
    // escaping, additionally removing everything that could be (html/javascript-) code
     $q = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_REQUEST['q'], ENT_QUOTES)));
     $aColumns = array('Nticket', 'incidencia');//Columnas de busqueda
     $sTable = "ticket";
     $sWhere = "";
    if ( $_GET['q'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".$q."%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }
    $sWhere.=" order by Nticket DESC";
    include 'pagination.php'; //include pagination file
    //pagination variables
    $page = (isset($_REQUEST['page']) && !empty($_REQUEST['page']))?$_REQUEST['page']:1;
    $per_page = 10; //how much records you want to show
    $adjacents  = 4; //gap between pages after number of adjacents
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
    //Count the total number of row in your table*/
    $count_query   = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) AS numrows FROM $sTable  $sWhere");
    $row= mysqli_fetch_array($count_query);
    $numrows = $row['numrows'];
    $total_pages = ceil($numrows/$per_page);
    $reload = './clientes.php';
    //main query to fetch the data
    $sql="SELECT * FROM  $sTable $sWhere LIMIT $offset,$per_page";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    //loop through fetched data
    if ($numrows>0){
        ?>
    <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table">
            <tr  class="danger">
                <th>ticket</th>
                <th>Incidencia</th>
                <th>Tema</th>
                <th>Detalle</th>
                <th>Funcionario</th>
                <th class='text-right'>Editar</th>
            </tr>
                <?php
        $nums=0;
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                    
                    $Nticket=$row['Nticket'];
                    $incidencia=$row['incidencia'];
                    $tema=$row['tema'];
                    $detalle=$row['detalle'];
                    
        $_FILES['imagen']['name']=$row['imagen']; 
                    $firstname=$row['firstname'];
                    $nums++;
                    ?>

                
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['Nticket'];?>" id="Nticket<?php echo $Nticket;?>">
             
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['incidencia'];?>" id="incidencia<?php echo $incidencia;?>">
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['tema'];?>" id="tema<?php echo $tema;?>">
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['detalle'];?>" id="detalle<?php echo $detalle;?>">
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['imagen'];?>" id="imagen<?php echo $_FILES['imagen']['name'];?>">
               <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['firstname'];?>" id="firstname">
                <tr>
                    
                   
                    <td><?php echo $Nticket; ?></td>
                     <td><?php switch ($incidencia){
         case  "Felicitaciones-sugerencias-quejas-reclamos";
          echo 'Felicitaciones-sugerencias-quejas-reclamos';
        break;
         case  "Aplicaciones moviles SwissSmart - R_sales":
           echo 'Aplicaciones moviles SwissSmart - R_sales';
        break;
                            
         case  "Reportes plataformasSwissSystem-SwissSmart-R_sales":
           echo 'Reportes plataformasSwissSystem-SwissSmart-R_sales';
        break;
                             case  "Soporte infraestructura":
           echo 'Soporte infraestructura';
        break;
                             case  "Soporte Software":
           echo 'Soporte Software SwissSystem, Acounting: Elias, siigo, swiss smart, syslog';
        break;
                             case  "Soporte Multimedia":
           echo 'Soporte Multimedia';
        break;
                             case  "Solicitud Capacitacion Software":
           echo 'Solicitud Capacitacion Software';
        break;
                             case  "Solicitud Capacitacion hardware":
           echo 'Solicitud Capacitacion hardware';
        break;
                             case  "Solicitud Desarrollo":
           echo 'Solicitud Desarrollo';
        break;
                             case  "Solcitud de equipos":
           echo 'Solcitud de equipos';
        break;
                             case  "Fallos conexiones servidores":
           echo 'Fallos conexiones servidores';
        break;
                             case  "Otros incidentes":
           echo 'Otros incidentes';
        break;
                            
                                } ?>
                     </td>
                    <td ><?php echo $tema; ?></td>
                    <td ><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal_<?php echo $nums; ?>"><li 
                   class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></li></a>
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal_<?php echo $nums; ?>" role="dialog">
           <div class="modal-dialog">
           <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;
              </button>
           <h4 class="modal-title">Detalle de la incidencia</h4>
       </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <p><?php echo $detalle;?></p>
  <a href='img/<?php echo $_FILES['imagen']['name']; ?>' target="_blank"> <p><img src="img/<?php echo $_FILES['imagen']['name']; ?>" 
    style="width: 100%;height: 100%"> </p>
</a>
     </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
      </div>

          </div>
     </div>
  </td>
                      <td><?php echo  $row['firstname']; ?></td>
                    
                    
                    <td class='text-right'>
                        
      <a href="#" class='btn btn-default' title='Editar ticket' onclick="obtener_datos('<?php echo $Nticket;?>');" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal21"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a> 
     </tr>
     <?php
    }
        
    ?>
    <tr>
     <td colspan=9><span class="pull-right">
     <?php
      echo paginate($reload, $page, $total_pages, $adjacents);
     ?></span></td>
    </tr>
     </table>
   </div>
   <?php
       
  }
    
}
?>
```

intente hacer algo asi pero no funciono

```
select count(*) From ticket ,

  var registrost = 5;

  var llamada_ajax= function() {


if ( registrost > registrosBD ){

    registrosBD =  registrosdes;

    Push.create("Tienes un nuevo ticket", {
    body: "$funcionario tiene una incidencia",
   icon: '/icon.png',
timeout: 4000,
onClick: function () {
    window.focus();
    this.close();

     }
       };

     var intervalo = 1000; //milisegundos
          setInterval(llamada_ajax, intervalo);






        }
      });
```

Comment: Por favor agrega el código js donde haces el ajax en mención !

Comment: *si hay un nuevo valor en una tabla o no y si lo hay que me mande una notificacion de que hay un nuevo valor...*  Ahí tienes la respuesta... haz la llamada a Ajax después de haber agregado nuevos elementos  a tu tabla.

Comment: esa es la cosa que no tengo muy claro como hacer la llamada

Comment: cual codigo ajax

Comment: Aquí en SO [hay varios ejemplos de cómo de hacen las peticiones Ajax](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/115575/29967). Entonces, tú puedes tener una bandera (un booleano) que controle cuando se agregan nuevos datos a la tabla, y activarlo en el `on.change` de tu tabla por ejemplo y si se agregaron filas lanzar la petición Ajax.  Si quieres ver cómo se hacen las peticiones Ajax, busca aquí mismo y encontrarás.

Comment: no no encontre ningun ejemplo puntual